# How to append a child div to a parent accordion by using the id of the child in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
$('<div>').attr('id', 'contentPanel'+i);
```

and I want to do somthing like:

```
$('#accordion').append('#contentPanel'+i);
```

The problem is that the div element is not added yet to the page and for that reason
I can't find the id of: $('#contentPanel'+i)

How can I catch dynamically declared element id and append it's id to another element?

Comment: It's very unclear, what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#placeholder').children('div').each(function () {
    $('#accordion').append($(this));
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/B6sKb/

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a string, `append` doesn't accept a selector, use `appendTo` instead:

```
$('#contentPanel'+i).appendTo('#accordion');
```

Comment: Hmmmmmm I'm thinking you might have interpreted the question better than me. If so I'll +1 you because you're right about the selector vs object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a jquery object to append method like this -

```
$('#accordion').append($('#contentPanel'+i));
```

Answer (score 0):

by **[append()](https://api.jquery.com/append/)**

```
  $('#accordion').append('<div id="contentPanel'+i+'"></div>');
```

**or**

```
$('#accordion').append($('#contentPanel'+i));
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is here:

```
 $('#accordion').append('#contentPanel'+i);
```

do like this:

```
 $('#accordion').append($('#contentPanel'+i));
```